# Skewed background just CSS

Tags: css

need divide background on two parts: [image: Example]

I have:

```css
body {
  background: #b6da8c;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #005370;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-10deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(-10deg);
  transform: skewX(-10deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

As you can see there is divided into 3 actually, how to change it to have 2 as on image?

Answer (score 1):

You could change the `transform-origin` to be at the bottom.

```css
body {
  background: #b6da8c;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #005370;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-10deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(-10deg);
  transform: skewX(-10deg);
  z-index: -1;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really simple fix without too much modification to your code. Just push the element off the screen and increase its width.

```
body { 
background: #b6da8c;
overflow: hidden;
}

body:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: -200px;
  width: 60%; height: 100%;
  background: #005370;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-10deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(-10deg);
  transform: skewX(-10deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background: #b6da8c;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #005370;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-10deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(-10deg);
  transform: skewX(-10deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```